# Start Date and End Date Of current month in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Hi had to first date and last date in any for current year in Mysql.

How to find in MySql in where clause?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @MonthStartDate As datetime
DECLARE @MonthEndDate As datetime
DECLARE @today datetime
SELECT @today = convert(varchar(12) , getdate() , 101) 

 SET @MonthStartDate = @today
 SELECT @MonthStartDate = dateadd ( dd , - datepart ( dd , @MonthStartDate ) ,  
 @MonthStartDate+1 )
 SELECT @MonthEndDate = dateadd(dd , -1 , dateadd ( mm , +1 , @MonthStartDate))
 SELECT @MonthStartDate AS StartDate , @MonthEndDate AS EndDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use between clause

like

```
select * from `table_name` where datetime_column as date between '01/01/2009' and curdate()
```

Comment: i want any month not for single month

Comment: this will give the result in between start date and end date, change your months which you want

Comment: hi sagar here i have to find first date but please tell me how to declare variable in mysql  *declare @date as datetime* (sql variable)